# Appended Href links to a list, but the list is showing only part of them

Tags: pandas, list, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i was scraping links out of this site below, there's over 4000 values but i managed to fetch only 78 to the list. While there was a nice output when i ran the first code saying it was all appended to the list

```
for i in range(1, 206):
   url = f"https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila?page%7Bi%7D=" ##added loop through pages function, turned string into variable
   page = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
   a = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila/'))
  list1=\[\]
  for ele in a:
     link = ele.get('href')
     list1.append(link)
     print(f"Appended link: {link}")
```

i scraped all the links out of it an got a nice little output of around 4000 links
now when i call out the list, using:
`print(list1)`

i get 78 links.

i've also tried making a csv file out of it, i get 78 rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list1)), columns = \['Link'\]) #adding the list to csv file

try:
df.to_csv('links.csv', index=False)
print("Links saved to CSV file successfully!") #adding expection to recognize error
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error saving links to CSV file: {e}")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and fix the indentation in code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all links into a DataFrame you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila?page='

all_links = []
for page in range(1, 207):
    print(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'{url}{page}').content, 'html.parser')
    all_links.extend(a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href*="/prodaja-automobila/"]'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Link': all_links})
print(df.head())
print(len(df))
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
...

204
205
206

                                                                                                                          Link
0                https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila/opel-insignia-grand-sport-1-6-cdti-ecotec-innovation-oglas-5143006
1                   https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila/isporuka-odmah-nissan-micra-1-0-ig-t-n-sport-novo-oglas-5147151
2               https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila/audi-a6-3-0-tdi-quattro-272ks-s-line-webasto-mmi-plus-oglas-5174610
3  https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila/vw-passat-variant-2-0-tdi-bmt-dsg-automatik-pdv-facelift-garancija-oglas-5175629
4                                            https://www.oglasnik.hr/prodaja-automobila/renault-megane-grandtour-oglas-3518246

4157
```

and saves `data.csv` with 4157 links (screenshot from Libre Office):

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, can u explain to me where did i go wrong in my code
and what does your code do vs mine

Comment: @Vandalism If I look at your code, you initialize `list1` to `[]` every iteration of first for-loop. So at the end it contains only elements from last iteration.

Comment: when i moved the list1=[] outside of the loop i would get 14xxx values which are duplicates, where do u think i went wrong with the loop?